# Factorization into factorial and combination?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations, factorial

> Is there a way or a general formula to write down all factorizations of $n!\  ( ∀ n ∈ N)$ into the factors which themselves are in factorial ($m!$) and combination ( $C(r,k)$ ) forms?
>
> And also is there a formula to calculate the total number of these different factorizations for each $n!$ ?

Please note that I want a formula which has two conditions; one for $(r,k ≤ n)$, and the other for $(r,k > n)$.

$∀ n ∈ N, n! = m! ×\dots × C(r,k) × \dots$

For example:

$$
\begin{align}
8! = 2! × 3! × 5! × C(8,6)\\ 
8! = 2! × 3! × C(8,6) × C(10,3)\\
8! = 2! × 3! × 3! × C(8,4) × C(8,7)\\
8! = 3! × 4! × C(7,4) × C(8,7)\\
8! = 3! × 5! × C(8,3)\\
8! = \dots\\
...
\end{align}
$$

and so on.